# Project Server 2013 - Soap Based approach

Tags: project-server, ms-project, project-online, project

We tried to access the Soap based requesting mechanism for project server 2013. For loginforms we found the below way to generate the request XML's in SoapUI using their end WSDL.

```
http://g2g-ps-2013:5555/pwa/_vti_bin/psi/loginforms.asmx?wsdl
```

The Requests and Response were successful. Now to the connect to figure out the Projects we used the below:

```
http://g2g-ps-2013:5555/pwa/_vti_bin/psi/project.asmx?wsdl
```

In this case, when trying with the endpoint "ReadProjectList" we ended up with no response

> Mon Feb 04 14:11:00 IST 2019:DEBUG:Stale connection check
>   Mon Feb 04 14:11:00 IST 2019:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
>   Mon Feb 04 14:11:00 IST 2019:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /pwa/_vti_bin/psi/project.asmx HTTP/1.1
>   Mon Feb 04 14:11:00 IST 2019:**DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.**
>   Mon Feb 04 14:11:00 IST 2019:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
>   Mon Feb 04 14:11:00 IST 2019:INFO:Got response for [ProjectSoap12.ReadProjectList:Request 1] in 289ms (0 bytes)

The same when simulated with Java Code gave:
Exception in connecting the MSProject server ,HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: **Connection refused: connect**

Please suggest on possible ways on resolving this discrepancy!

Answer (score 0):

Open (download) `.wsdl` in `XML` and find EndPoint URL, try to make a call on EndPoint, and not on `.wsdl`. Test web-services through third-party applications such as through the [SOAP UI](https://www.soapui.org/) at least you will make sure that the web service is working and the parameters for calling are detailed.

Comment: So Trivial, The reference URL provided there is to pick the WSDL dynamically for generating client. Indeed when u suggest SoapUI it picks the soap:address location which is nothing but the enpoint URL in which the request needs to be posted.

The query is specific to Project Server's expectation on the request format - Where we want to know if the system demands something exclusive for processing the request.

Comment: Understood, in my case, the call did not go to wsdl, but on EndPoint it solved the problem, good luck to you.